# Finding the longest substring in two strings C++

Tags: c++

I have to input 2 strings (they can include white characters, without new lines) and then find the longest substring which is in both of them.

There is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string tekst1, tekst2;
    
    int s1{}, s2{}, y{}, z{}, longest{};

    std::getline(std::cin, tekst1);
    std::getline(std::cin, tekst2);

    
    std::vector<char> chartekst1(tekst1.c_str(), tekst1.c_str() + tekst1.size() + 1);//converting string to char
    std::vector<char> chartekst2(tekst2.c_str(), tekst2.c_str() + tekst2.size() + 1);
    s1 = chartekst1.size();
    s2 = chartekst2.size();
    char* podciag = new char[s1];//temporary char - will contain substring

    for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < s2; t++)
        {
            y = i;
            z = t;
            while(chartekst1[y] == chartekst2[z] || y<s1 || z < s2)
            { 
                i = 0;
                podciag[i] = chartekst1[y];//adding same chars to tmp char array
                longest += 1;
                y++;
                z++;
                i++;
                std::cout << podciag[i];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm stuck and I don't know what should I do next. I'm getting a memory error `Debug Assertion Failed! - vector subscript out of range`. Could some1 help me?

Comment: "I would like to write it without using any algorithm." you mean without using one of the algorithms from the standard library?

Comment: Alogorithm like bubble sort etc

Comment: when you write some code that solves the problem, that is an algorithm by definition

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Just this https://imgur.com/a/MHYi4YS . I tried a lot of ways of changing loops arguments but it still doesn't work and error is the same

Comment: Just from briefly looking at it, should the while loop be using `&&`? Also we can't see the line numbers or where its going out of range, which would be helpful.

Comment: You are changing `i` inside the loop which also uses `i`, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: _"I would like to write it without using any algorithm"_ this is unclear for me. Can you explain?

Comment: The error means that you have an out-of-bounds access. You can try to change access via `[]` to access via `at` to get a more helpful error

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a lot of issues:

1. You are converting `string` to `vector` for no good reason. String can be accessed directly using `[index]` or preferably using `.at(index)`. No need for `vector` at all. Even if you did not wish to use default `string` indexers, you can use its `c_str()` which is a `const char*` that you can use `[]` against.
2. Your loops are very unclear. You are repeating variables `i` and `t` for no good reason. Then in the innermost body, you are modifying `i` which will also affect the first loop. You should not modify a loop variable unless you know you should. And even then, you'll run into problems.
3. The modification of `i` in your innermost block of code is what causes the debug assert error. `vector` is better accessed using `.at(index)` instead of `[index]`. The latter raises a debug assert in some implementations (e.g. MSVC++) and cannot be caught by `try/catch` block since it's not a C++ exception. So avoid using it on `vector` at all costs.

---

I wrote a quicky code that solves your problem without using any pre-existing algorithms. I was not aiming for best Big O in either space or time complexities. So take it with a pinch of salt. It can sure be optimized heavily for performance. But for now, it does the job.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // small is copy of the smaller string, large is similar
  std::string tekst1, tekst2, small, large;

  // scan strings from standard input device
  std::getline(std::cin, tekst1);
  std::getline(std::cin, tekst2);

  // determine which of the two inputs is smaller, assign small/large accordingly
  size_t s1, s2; 
  s1 = tekst1.size();
  s2 = tekst2.size(); 

  if (s1 > s2) {
    small = tekst2; 
    large = tekst1; 
  }
  else {
    small = tekst1; 
    large = tekst2;
  }

  // update s1 and s2 to reflect small and large lengths respectively
  // this is done to make looping easier
  s1 = small.size(); 
  s2 = large.size();

  // sub_small is to take sub-string from small string for comparison
  // sub_large is the sub-string from large for comparison
  std::string sub_small, sub_large;

  // set max length as length of small - this is max allowed length
  // this can only happen if small string is completely contained 
  // within large string
  size_t max_length = s1;

  size_t i, j; // i declared them outside of loop if you wish to use them later
  bool match = false; 

  // try matching sub-strings from max_length all the way down to 0
  while (max_length > 0) {
    // start with small string, take substring from it, compare to
    // all possible max_length subsets taken from the large string
    // if any match was found, break everything. if none, repeat
    for (i = 0; i < s1 && i + max_length <= s1; i++) {
      sub_small = small.substr(i, max_length); 

      for (j = 0; j < s2 && j + max_length <= s2; j++) {
        sub_large = large.substr(j, max_length); 
        match = sub_small == sub_large;
        if (match) break;
      }
      if (match) break;
    }
    if (match) break;
    max_length--;
  };

  std::cout << std::endl;

  if (match) {
    std::cout << "Largest matching sub-string has size [ " << max_length << " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: \"" << sub_small << "\""<< std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Could not find any matching substrings!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Please note:

1. The code will tell if it found any substring using `match` variable.
2. The code allows you to tell where the found sub-string starts within the smaller and larger strings. To do so, see `i` and `j` representing starting index of found match (if any) within `small` and `large` respectively.